# Using SNat from Data.Singletons like other Sing instances?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, singleton-type

I can use `SomeSing` with great effect to be able to dynamically generate Singletons and then pattern-match on them to be able to do fun stuff

```
> let x = SomeSing SFalse :: SomeSing ('KProxy :: KProxy Bool)
-- pretend x is dynamically generated using IO or something
> case x of SomeSing SFalse -> blah blah
            SomeSing STrue -> blah blah
```

However, I'm not really sure how to do this with `SNat`, which is the data family instance for `Sing Nat`.  One issue I have is that I'm not able to ever get the `SNat` data constructor in scope even when importing all of the relevant modules (`Data.Singletons`, `Data.Singletons.TypeLits`, `Data.Singletons.Prelude`, etc.) and enabling the extensions (even though `SNat` the constructor shows up when I use `:browse` and `:i Sing`)

...another issue I have is that ... there aren't any separate constructors to match on like for `SFalse` and `STrue`...there's just one constructor! :O  How am I supposed to use this in the same way?

Comment: Putting any singleton into an existential wrapper simply makes it isomorphic to the original type (ie, `SomeSing (KProxy :: KProxy x)` is inhabited by as many values as `x`, *if* your singleton is constructed properly). This should be obvious when you remember that a singleton shares the same structure as its parent datatype but encodes more information at the type level, and `SomeSing` erases all that information. So long story short: `SomeSing SNat` is just [`Natural`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-Natural.html#t:Natural).

Comment: @user2407038 yes, I see that...but how can I get the `Natural` from the `SomeSing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that there are two natural number singleton types both called `SNat`. The one you seem to have found goes with GHC typelits. Its constructor is not exported from the defining module, but it's an `Integer` underneath. You can access that integer, but the whole thing seems to be pretty much useless for proofs. The other `SNat` version deals with the classic Peano naturals. It'll work for proofs, but will be slow at runtime. I've not yet seen a Haskell natural good for both proofs and speed.

Comment: I'm interested in accessing the `Integer`...I'm not using it for proofs, I'm just using it to dynamically initialize my program, which deals with things like `V n Double`'s, but is always polymorphic over all `n`.  I'd like to get the `n` from runtime things, like the result of IO actions.

Comment: @JustinL, what do you need the type-level addition for in that case? You might want to play with the latest version of `reflection`.

Comment: @dfeur it looks like `reflection` gives me what i wanted.  thanks! :)